# SMTP Connections in Lotus domino

Tags: email, smtp, ibm-domino

Yahoo limits the number of messages that can be sent per SMTP connection to 5. (see. http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/basics/postmaster-38.html;_ylt=AmQ249AWdyWDPc9ZukN6VGkIJHdG)

We typically have users with large email distribution lists and easily exceed 5 yahoo addresses.  Does anyone know how to have Lotus Domino increase the number of connections?

Right now when users send a message with more than 5 the connection get's killed then hangs and tries again later but the process seems to really slow down mail delivery.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are wanting to email FROM a Domino server TO various recipients at Yahoo and you are following suggestions [here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/basics/postmaster-38.html;_ylt=Ap6lhRbHQNMFl1MZWS9ZOwQIJHdG) and are trying to add more concurrent connections.

See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/DOC/H_CUSTOMIZING_MESSAGE_TRANSFER_STEPS.html) for some help on that - the top two fields in the table would be what you're after.